# Booking.com cancelation fee

Tags: international-travel, money, regulations, refunds, booking.com

What happens if I have missed free cancelation period and now to cancel reservation I have to be charged 500 Euros from booking.com, however, I do not have that amount available in My Revolut (which I linked to the reservation).

Comment: Have you already paid for the booking? If so, how much? The cancellation fee is more likely to be taken off any refund they would make.

Comment: I have not paid anything, I have to pay when i arrive at the accoomodation, however, I forgot to cancel the booking within the free cancelation period, and now in order to cancel, I have to pay the fee, which is the full price of the accomodation (500 euros)

Comment: They will try to charge the card you provided when you don’t show up or when you cancel. If the funds are not available they will most certainly try to contact you to settle your debt. Is there a specific reason for the cancellation (e.g. changes in Covid rules)? Are you sure they are not covered by current policies?

Comment: Try to contact booking.com (maybe they can cancel the cancellation fee: it depends on your history with them and the mood of the customer office you talk). Else, try to contact the hotel. The hotel may need to pay a commission to booking, but possibly it is smaller than 500 euros. Or try to find someone which want to travel instead of you (hotels are less picky on changing names, but ask them before trying to do this)

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing here

1. Booking.com will try to collect the money from the Revolut account. This will trigger the following events: https://www.revolut.com/en-US/help/my-accounts/managing-my-account/what-happens-if-my-balance-goes-negative
2. If Booking can't get all the money from your Revolut account, they will try to collect some other way. This can take all different forms and shapes depending on the amount and your local legislation so it's hard to predict how this would look like. They may give up quickly, they may take formal legal action which could result in substantial fees, cost, effort and trouble for you.

Frankly, the right thing to do is to pay, either through the Revolut account or some other means. You entered a contract and as much as you expect your contract partners to keep their obligations, the same is expected from you.

I understand that this is an expensive and unfortunate mistake, but in the end it's your mistake, not theirs.

Paying will also make this go away with the least amount of effort and with no blemishes on your records.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi That's the exact same link I posted in my answer ??

Comment: The truth is that the free cencallation period was due the 26th of July, however, due to the recent Covid-19 measures implied in the reagion of the accomodation, I called the landlord personally and we had a verbal agreement that the free cencallation can be extended until the 28th of July (today). Today I have tried to cancel it through booking but I have to pay the fees, as the period was not extended on the website. for that reason I had to request a free cancellation which the landlord has to accept from the website, as promised. If they trick me I will be charged.

Comment: @Hilmar: sorry: I read several time your answer and I do not know how I missed the link. Sorry

Comment: @Dolfoner: why don't you just call booking directly?